# Pie chart in Javascript does not work correctly

Tags: javascript

I was working on a pie chart, which works fine for all fields except the red one. When you enter the mouse in the upper red field close to yellow, it does not work and the scaling option is not trigged. It is some sort of layering issue regarding the different pie sections which I could not resolve unfortunately. Hopefully someone has any idea, thank you very much in advance!

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

    .pieContainer {
      height: 150px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .pieBackground {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    } 

    .pie {
      transition: all 0.4s;
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      clip: rect(0px, 75px, 150px, 0px);
    }

    .hold {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 75px);
      transition: 1s all ;
    }


    .innerCircle {
      position: absolute;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      background-color: #444;
      border-radius: 100%;
      top: 15px;
      left: 15px; 
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
      color: white;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .innerCircle .content {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      top: 30px;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .flex-center{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class='flex-center'>
  <div class="pieContainer">
    <div class="pieBackground"></div>

    <div class="innerCircle">
      <div class="content">
      <b>Data</b><br>from 16<sup>th</sup> April, 2014</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

  <script>
    let arr=[
      {size:2,color:'red'},
      {size:2,color:'blue'},
      {size:1,color:'green'},
      {size:3,color:'yellow'}
    ];
    let pieContainer = document.querySelector('.pieContainer')
    let rotate = 0;
    let point = 360/(arr.reduce((acc, cur) =>acc + cur.size,0))
    let half = (arr.reduce((acc, cur) =>acc + cur.size,0))/2

    let firstHold = null;

    arr.forEach((i,k)=>{


      let hold = document.createElement('div')
      hold.className = 'hold'
      let pie = document.createElement('div')
      pie.className = 'pie'
      pieContainer.appendChild(hold)
      hold.appendChild(pie)


      if (k === 0 ) {
        firstHold = hold;
      }

      if(i.size >  half){
        let littlePiece = i.size - half

        pie.style.transform = `rotate(${point*half}deg)`;
        hold.style.transform = `rotate(${rotate}deg)`;
        rotate+=point*half;
        pie.style.backgroundColor = i.color;

        let littlehold = document.createElement('div')
        littlehold.className = 'hold'
        let littlepie = document.createElement('div')
        littlepie.className = 'pie'
        pieContainer.appendChild(littlehold)
        littlehold.appendChild(littlepie)
        littlepie.style.transform = `rotate(${point*littlePiece}deg)`;
        littlehold.style.transform = `rotate(${rotate}deg)`;
        rotate+=point*littlePiece;
        littlepie.style.backgroundColor = i.color;


      }else{
        pie.style.transform = `rotate(${point*i.size}deg)`;
        hold.style.transform = `rotate(${rotate}deg)`;
        let rotatePos = hold.style.transform
        pie.onmouseenter = function(){

          if (k !== 1) {

          firstHold.style.zIndex = 3
          }
          hold.style.cursor = 'pointer'
          hold.style.transform = `${rotatePos} scale(1.2)`;
          document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerHTML =  i.size

        }
        pie.onmouseleave = function(){
          hold.style.transform = rotatePos;
          firstHold.style.zIndex = 0;
        }
        rotate+=point*i.size;
        pie.style.backgroundColor = i.color;
      }


    })



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerGlove is on the right track.  I'm not sure what the best approach is to fix this problem.  But I went ahead and adjusted some of the styles so that you can see what is happening.  Because the Yellow div is created last, it is "in-front" of the Red div, and so either the yellow div or the corresponding hold div associated with it is blocking the red div from getting a mouse-enter event message.
I tried setting a z-index value to put the red div in front but that didn't seem to help.
I would suggest transforming the scale of the div by itself -- instead of transforming both the "hold" and the colored div.  In other words - simplify the structure by removing the "hold" div.

You can see from this example that the yellow div is always "on top".
https://js-3q9xfr.stackblitz.io

Comment: I just came across another pie chart - that uses a free library called Raphael...
Check it out here: http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/pie.html

Comment: @ b0rgBart3, thanks for your effort! actually I aimed to do it without a library, in case I will find it out, I ll give an update.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with ZIndex. If you add `display:none` to the yellow sector the red one works each time on mouse enter. Btw, nice work accomplishing this with DIVs.